# Jitter texture generation

Tags: opengl, rendering, texture, sampling, hlsl

I am currently reading the awesome paper by Jorge Jimenez about Character rendering : [Next Generation Character Rendering](http://www.iryoku.com/stare-into-the-future)

In the part about multi-sampled transmittance he uses some Poisson offsets and a jitter texture which contains *[cos(x), sin(x)]* and is used to rotate the the Poisson disk samples.

But I am wondering how do you generate such texture ?

Here is the part of the ppt which talks about this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The texture is probably generated by picking a random angle per pixel, and populating the image with its sine and cosine, remapped into [0, 1]:

$$\theta \sim [0, 2\pi] \quad \to \quad \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2} \cos \theta + \tfrac{1}{2} \\ \tfrac{1}{2} \sin \theta + \tfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I did a quick test and generated something that looks pretty similar (enlarged 4x):

[image]

If you want to be extra fancy, then instead of picking independent random angles for every pixel, you might try stratified sampling or a low-discrepancy sequence. That may give better final results for whatever effect you're using the jitter texture for, due to better local sample distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, could you tell me more about stratified sampling and low-discrepancy sequence ?

Comment: For reference, here is the source for a low discrepancy sample (blue noise) generator https://github.com/bartwronski/BlueNoiseGenerator